# how can we Hijack DLL to lock all directories in windows to verify

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll-injection

I mean when we double click a directory,in requests us to verify.I think it can be done by dll-injection.Hope can give some ideas or tutorial.Thanks

Comment: refer tour to learn how and what kind of question should be asked.

Comment: Ummmm,I mean I want to design a kind of tool that every time I open a directory that contains some important files in windows, it detects this event can ask the user to verify permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hijack DLL is not required. It use Window Message Hook.
At the first, create DLL that call SetWindowsHookEx.

```
hHookMsg = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)MsgProc, hInstance, 0);
```

For example, called `install_hook`, And MsgProc here

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(INT nCode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
  CHAR className[256];
  MSG *pmsg;
  LVHITTESTINFO htif;
  POINT pt;

  pmsg = (MSG*)lp;
  GetClassName(pmsg->hwnd, className, sizeof(className));
  if (!strcmp(className, "SysListView32")) {
    if (pmsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) {
      GetCursorPos((LPPOINT)&pt);
      htif.pt = pt;
      ScreenToClient(pmsg->hwnd, &htif.pt);
      SendMessage(pmsg->hwnd, LVM_HITTEST, 0, (LPARAM)&htif);
      if ((htif.flags & LVHT_ONITEM) != 0) {
          // you can write action here
      }
    }
  }
  return CallNextHookEx( hHookMesg, nCode, wp, lp );
}
```

And create EXE that call this install_hook.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! but there are still some puzzle that how come this install_hook can detect all event of opening a directory? /LOL

Comment: I commented this since you mentioned double-click. But if you want to detect file changes, you can use ReadDirectoryChanges recursibly, I guess.